# spring boot not loading default profile while using spring.profile.default in application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-profiles

**FYI : I swear there is no activating profile configuration such as -D or run configuration**

## Goal

When application is booted up without any activating profile, the `dev` profile is activated as a default.

## Problem

I've set `spring.profile.default = dev` , and I would expect that the dev profile is activated. But it is not.

## What I did

`Run Environment`

Spring-Boot-version : 2.1.2 Release

`What I'm referred`

1) How to use profiles in Spring Boot Application - 
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2019/07/profiles-spring-boot-application.html#respond

**Here's Code What I did**

`/resources/application.properties`

```
spring.profiles.default= dev

application.environment=This is a "Default" Environment
```

`/resources/application-dev.properties`

```
application.environment=This is a "dev" Environment
server.port= 8082
```

`/ProfileController.java`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class ProfileController {

    @Value("${application.environment}")
    private String applicationEnv;

    @GetMapping
    public String getApplicationEnv(){
        return applicationEnv;
    }
}
```

## Result

localhost/v1 => This is a "Default" Environment

And

I've found out the default profile is set up as `dev` correctly.

This is my spring-boot log.

> 2019-10-16 23:17:02.926  INFO 64099 --- [           main] c.e.s.SpringbootdemoappApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: dev

## Add another log for server port

> 2019-10-17 00:25:03.837  INFO 68318 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8083 (http)

The reason that I add is it doesn't seem a problem related with Injection.

## Time to Close this question

The first goal that I want to achieve is change default profile.
From spring docs(https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition-profiles-default), default profile can be changed as setting `spring.profiles.default` in `application.properties`.

But it seems kind of bug (Thanks @Antoniossss). Even if I've set that in `application.properties` and the console showed `No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: dev`.
However still `dev` profile wasn't activated.

The thing that I've found out is **changing default profile should be done before loading application.properties**.

It means if changing default profile is described in `application.properties`, it's too late.(IDK why though, I can't figure out because there are so many layers in Spring ...)
If défaut profile is set up using `-Dspring.default.profile = dev` , it's working properly.

From https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1219:

> You can't change the default profile by declaring it in a config file. It has to be in place before the config files are read.

Comment: Can you try `spring.profiles.active=dev`?

Comment: @HasanCanSaral Are you meaning that add `spring.profile.active=dev` in `application-dev.properties` ?

Comment: Yes. It is working as expected. If you had `spring.profiles.active=someOtherProfile` you would have the `someOtherProfile` activated. If you have nothing, by `spring.profiles.default` you set your fallback to `dev`.

Comment: @HasanCanSaral So, I didn't set up *any active profile*. and I would expect `dev` will be activate. Because default profile is `dev`

Comment: @Antoniossss I can't say Dev is activated. Dev is set up as default. 
And if there is no activated profile, default profile might be activated. But it is not.
It's a problem

Comment: change `spring.profiles.default= dev`  to `spring.profiles.default=dev` ?? Idk should work just like that imho.

Comment: @Antoniossss still doesn't work :-l ...

Comment: can you point me to docs where do you find this property `spring.profile.default ` ? @MinwooKang

Comment: @Deadpool Actually I was following this article(https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2019/07/profiles-spring-boot-application.html#respond), but give me some time to find from docs.

Comment: I don't think spring has that property, you need to use `spring.profiles.active` @MinwooKang https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: It is/was a bug - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1219

Comment: @Deadpool FYI : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition-profiles-default

Comment: it is new thing to know @MinwooKang thanks

Comment: so you have set this property `spring.profile.default = dev` in application.properties? or how are you passing it to spring application? @MinwooKang

Comment: Yes I have set this property to change default profiles. But It didn't work what I expected.

But I've found out how to change default profile. I will update in description

Comment: @Deadpool Yes that's the answer what I want :) Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are passing this properties after application is loaded, you need to provide this property while application is booting up

**Pass it as JVM args**

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.default=dev myproject.jar
```

**Pass as environment variable**

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.profiles.default=dev
```

**System variable**

```
SPRING_PROFILES_DEFAULT=dev
```

Comment: Yes It's totally working.

You've found out the answer in a few seconds. I've spent so many times to figure out though 

Answer (score 0):

You have only configured the default profile.
You need to set an active profile like `spring.profiles.active=dev`
in your app properties. For injecting current active profile,

```
@Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
private String currentActiveEnv;
```

Comment: Can I ask you why? Default profile is different from active?

In my perspective, if there is no activated profile, the default profile should be activate. Isn't it?

Comment: @MinwooKang In the snippet, you have mentioned the default profile as dev. And it seems that dev is properly activated. Are you asking why you're not getting 'This is a "dev" Environment' in the response? That could probably be happening since you are injecting @Value("${application.environment}") instead of active profile to the variable.

Comment: Oh, thanks for inspiring new insight .. It could be .. but in `dev` profile, I've set up `sever.port = 8082`, but tomcat was started in 8083 port which is described in `application.properties`. 

 It makes me more confusing. If the `dev` profile is activated correctly, the sever port should be 8082 and there might be no doubt about this.

Answer (score 0):

You set your default profile fallback to `dev` with `spring.profiles.default=dev`. If you had `spring.profiles.active=someOtherProfile`, you would have `someOtherProfile` activated.

> 2019-10-16 23:17:02.926 INFO 64099 --- [ main]
>   c.e.s.SpringbootdemoappApplication : No active profile set, falling
>   back to default profiles: dev

This log says that `dev` profile is the active one, since you don't have any explicit profile activated.

Comment: Yes, You're right. 
But as you can see in result, the `application.environment` is still `Default` value.

Comment: Did you try with `spring.profiles.active`? I suspect the properties of your fallback profile might not be loaded if there's no explicit profile set.

Comment: What value do I need to put in `spring.profiles.active`? 
But default property(it means `application.properties`) is loaded correctly. Because the server was booted in the port that I described in `application.properties`.

Comment: `spring-profiles-active=dev`. As I said, in case your application falls back to default profile (in your case, `dev`), your `application.properties` might be loaded instead of `application-dev.properties`. Explicitly setting your active profile might be needed.

Comment: Oh , `falling back to default profiles: dev` means that the `application.properties` will be loaded?
I might have misunderstanding about setting up default ...
When I set default profile as `dev`, I would expect the default profile will be `dev` and there is no activated profile, therefore falling back to `dev` ... but it seems not .. right?

Comment: Thats's what I suspect. I would expect the same as what you do, but it might not be how it works.

Comment: Sounds like a little weird ... but you know what, the link that I've referred are saying `2019-07-07 20:35:23.587  INFO 16832 — [           main] c.b.j.s.SpringbootprofilesApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: dev
So it is clear from above logs that dev is now treated as default profile.`

And he was succeed ... I really want to tag him in here though

Answer (score 0):

Please go through with following link -

https://medium.com/@khandkesoham7/profiling-with-spring-boot-408b33f8a25f

that guy has explained well

and to verify the or command for generate the build follow the following command

> `mvn -Ppreprod package -DskipTests clean verify`